# How can I delete product? in MongoDB using axios

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, axios

Create and Update was flawless however I have a problem with Delete Product with Mongodb, Mongoose, Axios and Next.js

Is there any permission did i have to grant to the App or my method is wrong all together?

Here is the code

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import Product from '../../../../../models/Product';
import db from '../../../../../utils/db';

const handler = async (req, res) => {
    const user = await getToken({ req });
    if (!user || (user && !user.isAdmin)) {
    return res.status(401).send('signin required');
  }

  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    return getHandler(req, res, user);
  } else if (req.method === 'PUT') {
    return putHandler(req, res, user);
  } else if (req.method === 'DELETE') {
    return deleteHandler(req, res, user);
  } else {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Method not allowed' });
  }
};
const getHandler = async (req, res) => {
  await db.connect();
  const product = await Product.findById(req.query.id);
  await db.disconnect();
  res.send(product);
};
const putHandler = async (req, res) => {
  await db.connect();
  const product = await Product.findById(req.query.id);
  if (product) {
    product.name = req.body.name;
    product.slug = req.body.slug;
    product.price = req.body.price;
    product.category = req.body.category;
    product.image = req.body.image;
    product.brand = req.body.brand;
    product.countInStock = req.body.countInStock;
    product.description = req.body.description;
    await product.save();
    await db.disconnect();
    res.send({ message: 'Product updated successfully' });
  } else {
    await db.disconnect();
    res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product not found' });
  }
};
const deleteHandler = async (req, res) => {
    await db.connect();
    const product = await Product.findById(req.query.id);
    if (product) {
      await product.remove();
      await db.disconnect();
      res.send({ message: 'Product deleted successfully' });
    } else {
      await db.disconnect();
      res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product not found' });
    }
};  
export default handler;
```

Here is the terminal error:

```
error pages/api/admin/users/[id].js (25:15) @ remove
- error Error [TypeError]: user.remove is not a function
    at deleteHandler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/admin/users/[id].js:36:20)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  digest: undefined
}
  23 |       return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Can not delete admin' });
  24 |     }
> 25 |     await user.remove();
     |               ^
  26 |     await db.disconnect();
  27 |     res.send({ message: 'User Deleted' });
  28 |   } else {
```

here is the frontend :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import { getError } from '../../utils/error';
import Hero from '@/components/Hero';

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: '' };
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loading: false, products: action.payload, error: '' };
    case 'FETCH_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case 'CREATE_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loadingCreate: true };
    case 'CREATE_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loadingCreate: false };
    case 'CREATE_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loadingCreate: false };
    case 'DELETE_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loadingDelete: true };
    case 'DELETE_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loadingDelete: false, successDelete: true };
    case 'DELETE_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loadingDelete: false };
    case 'DELETE_RESET':
      return { ...state, loadingDelete: false, successDelete: false };

    default:
      state;
  }
}
export default function AdminProdcutsScreen() {
    const router = useRouter();

    const [
      { loading, error, products, loadingCreate, successDelete, loadingDelete },
      dispatch,
    ] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: true,
    products: [],
    error: '',
  });

  const createHandler = async () => {
    if (!window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_REQUEST' });
      const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/admin/products`);
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_SUCCESS' });
      toast.success('Product created successfully');
      router.push(`/admin/product/${data.product._id}`);
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_FAIL' });
      toast.error(getError(err));
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' });
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/admin/products`);
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAIL', payload: getError(err) });
      }
    };

    if (successDelete) {
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_RESET' });
      } else {
        fetchData();
      }
    }, [successDelete]);
  
    const deleteHandler = async (productId) => {
      if (!window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        return;
      }
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_REQUEST' });
        await axios.delete(`/api/admin/products/${productId}`);
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_SUCCESS' });
        toast.success('Product deleted successfully');
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_FAIL' });
        toast.error(getError(err));
      }
    };
  return (
    <div>
        <Hero heading="Admin Products"/>
        <div>
        <div className="grid md:grid-cols-4 md:gap-5">
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link href="/admin/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/admin/orders">Orders</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/admin/products" className="font-bold">
                Products
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link href="/admin/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="overflow-x-auto md:col-span-3">
        <div className="flex justify-between">
            <h1 className="mb-4 text-xl">Products</h1>
            {loadingDelete && <div>Deleting item...</div>}
            <button
              disabled={loadingCreate}
              onClick={createHandler}
              className="primary-button"
            >
              {loadingCreate ? 'Loading' : 'Create'}
            </button>
          </div>
          {loading ? (
            <div>Loading...</div>
          ) : error ? (
            <div className="alert-error">{error}</div>
          ) : (
            <div className="overflow-x-auto">
              <table className="min-w-full">
                <thead className="border-b">
                  <tr>
                    <th className="px-5 text-left">ID</th>
                    <th className="p-5 text-left">NAME</th>
                    <th className="p-5 text-left">PRICE</th>
                    <th className="p-5 text-left">CATEGORY</th>
                    <th className="p-5 text-left">COUNT</th>
                    <th className="p-5 text-left">RATING</th>
                    <th className="p-5 text-left">ACTIONS</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {products.map((product) => (
                    <tr key={product._id} className="border-b">
                      <td className=" p-5 ">{product._id.substring(20, 24)}</td>
                      <td className=" p-5 ">{product.name}</td>
                      <td className=" p-5 ">${product.price}</td>
                      <td className=" p-5 ">{product.category}</td>
                      <td className=" p-5 ">{product.countInStock}</td>
                      <td className=" p-5 ">{product.rating}</td>
                      <td className=" p-5 ">
                      <Link
                          href={`/admin/product/${product._id}`}
                          type="button"
                          className="default-button"
                        >
                          Edit
                        </Link>
                        &nbsp;
                        <button
                          onClick={() => deleteHandler(product._id )}
                          className="default-button"
                          type="button"
                        >
                          Delete
                        </button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

AdminProdcutsScreen.auth = { adminOnly: true };
```

Whenever I click on Delete button it returns error 500 internal server error I dont have a clue what is going on

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(product)` after line `const product = await Product.findById(req.query.id);`

Comment: Looking the error you are trying to delete the user not product,
Also, to remove you need to pass the query for example: `db.collection.remove({ _id: some_id })` to remove the matching _id or `db.collection.remove({ })` for removing all the rows in collection. Also, check your mongoose version for remove function or you can try `findOneAndDelete({_id: your_product_id})` to delete the particular row in the collection